# SWIFT 4 UISearchBar Not Loading Images

Tags: uitableview, swift4, uisearchbar, xcode9

I am extremely new to Xcode and swift and currently working on a school project. I have linked the UISearchBar to the UITableView and am able to search properly. However, the issue I am having is when I use the search bar to click on an item the image linked to the item won't pop up on the next page. It works well when I don't search the item and click right from table view. Here's my code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var schoolSearch: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!


let schoolnames = ["Long Beach City College LAC", "California State University, Bakersfield", "California State University, Cal Maritime", "California State University, Channel Islands", "California State University, Chico", "California State University, Dominguez Hills", "California State University, East Bay", "California State University, Fresno", "California State University, Fullerton", "California State University, Humboldt", "California State University, Long Beach", "California State University, Los Angeles", "California State University, Monterey Bay", "California State University, Northridge", "California State Polytechnic University, Pomona", "California State University, Sacramento", "California State University, San Bernardino", "California State University, San Diego", "California State University, San Francisco", "California State University, San Jose", "California Polytechnic State University, San Luis Obispo", "California State University, San Marcos", "California State University, Sonoma", "California State University, Stanislaus", "University of California Berkeley", "University of California Davis", "University of California Irvine", "University of California Los Angeles", "University of California Merced", "University of California Riverside", "University of California San Diego", "University of California San Francisco",  "University of California Santa Barbara", "University of California Santa Cruz", "Long Beach City College PCC", "El Camino College Torrance", "El Camino College Compton", "Cerritos College", "Cypress College"]

var searchedSchool = [String]()
var searching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    schoolSearch.delegate = self

    self.tblView.delegate = self
    self.tblView.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
}
extension ChooseSchool: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchedSchool.count
    } else {
        return schoolnames.count
    }
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
      cell?.img.image = UIImage(named: schoolnames[indexPath.row])
      cell?.lbl.text = schoolnames[indexPath.row]

      _ = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
      if searching {
           cell?.textLabel?.text = searchedSchool[indexPath.row]
      } else{
           cell?.textLabel?.text = schoolnames[indexPath.row]
      }
      return cell!
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestController") as? TestController
 vc?.schoolnames = schoolnames[indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
 searchedSchool = schoolnames.filter { $0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
    searching = true
    tblView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    tblView.reloadData()
}
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your data source: schoolnames vs searchedSchool. In you didSelectRowAt you have to set condition.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestController") as? TestController
if searching {
vc?.schoolnames = searchedSchool[indexPath.row]
} else {
 vc?.schoolnames = schoolnames[indexPath.row]
}
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```